Screen Sharing in Plasma 6 & Wayland on 22.04
I am trying to get to work screen sharing under wayland, which is quite a difficult story it seems.
Anyone here, has some advise how to manage this?
Here are some specs:
Operating System: KDE neon 6.0
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.5.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-119-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 30.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: AMD Radeon Graphics
Manufacturer: SLIMBOOK
Product Name: PROX-AMD5

Here are some packages I have installed:
apt list --installed |grep xdg

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

python3-xdg/jammy,now 0.27-2 all  [Installiert,automatisch]
xdg-dbus-proxy/jammy,now 0.1.3-1 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk/jammy,now 1.14.0-1build1 amd64  [installiert]
xdg-desktop-portal-kde/jammy,now 6.1.4-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build66 amd64  [installiert]
xdg-desktop-portal/jammy,now 1.18.4-1+22.04+jammy+release+build1 amd64  [installiert]
xdg-user-dirs/jammy,now 0.18-1+22.04+jammy+release+build7 amd64  [Installiert,automatisch]
xdg-utils/jammy,jammy,now 1.2.1-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build5 all  [Installiert,automatisch]

Problem is:
When i try to start Screensharing via firefox (flatpak) I can choose windows, desktops etc.
When I choose one the red dot (xdg-*-kde) start in the systemtray but nothing happens – The screen is not shared.
Testing it with mozilla github webrtc-landing is just empty reporting no success or anything else…
Any hints here?

Downgrading xdg-desktop-portal did the trick!
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal=1.14.3-0ubuntu

From:
https://discuss.kde.org/t/kde-neon-plasma-6-1-screen-sharing-error-in-wayland/17334/11?u=dr.axelbauer
